# Cancel scrolling on HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have a page in HTML5

The page is defined as **100% height**, and still have a scroll bar.

At first I thought it was because the Google Map that I have in the page, and then I opened the page in another browser, scroll bar smaller than the first browser,

then I got the idea that it is because of the different **Tool Bars**.

Is it really because of the Tool bar or is it because of the map, and how to fix it?

Thank you...

My css:

```
.ui-mobile
{
    height: 99%;
    width: 100%;
}

ui-mobile-viewport.ui-overlay-c
{
    height: 99%;

}

#map_canvas
{
    height: 99%;
    width: 100%;
    position: inherit;
}
```

My Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
...
    <title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainPage" data-role="page">
        <script>
            $("#MainPage").live("pageinit", function () { ... });
        </script>
        <div id="map_canvas">
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't need scrollbars at all, you can set `html { overflow-y: hidden; }`. Otherwise, there is probably a default margin, which you can remove by `* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }`

Comment: I define elements have to be at the bottom and then if there is no scrolling I do not see them

Comment: I want the page will ignore Tool bars and begin the calculations of the percentages below. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not a problem for you take a look at my jQuery solution:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    var screenHeight= 0;
    screenHeight= $('[data-role="page"]').first().height() - $('[data-role="header"]').first().height()- $('[data-role="footer"]').first().height();
    $('#map_canvas').css('height',screenHeight - 4);
}).trigger('resize');
```

**Page height - header height - footer height - 4 = content height**

I am using - 4 to counter borders. Use only -2 if you have only footer or header. None if you have only map.

For this formula you need a viewpoint meta tag set, because you will get wrong screen sizes.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

This is a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HKjEF/

Tested in Win Firefox, iPad Safari, Android 4.1 Chrome environments.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please share HTML code.

For your question : Yes, it may be because of **Tool Bars** or some other default margin, padding in the page.

You can remove the scroll-bar by setting height as 98% or 99% which ever fix scrolling issue for you.